# TypeError: custom() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'---yolov7

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, yolo, yolov5

i am trying to load  yolov7 model ( for the weights which i am trained for my dataset ) but i am get error

```
model = torch.hub.load('yolov7','custom', path='/home/runs/train/yolov7x-custom/weights/best.pt',force_reload=True,source='local')
```

[image]

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc" - from [this page which you should definitely read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me :), since yolov7 they changed path param to path_or_model param

```
MODEL = torch.hub.load('.', 'custom',
                       path_or_model=MODEL_PATH,
                       source='local',
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-clone the repository and place your model in "/home/runs/train/yolov7x-custom/weights" path, or easily you can clone the repo (`!git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7.git`) then run the detect script:

> !python3 detect.py --source path to image --weights path ro
> weights

Comment: i am try for real time detection ,so your second approach  how it can help me  bez i am try to laod yolov7-model in model then i use opencv for detection by send frame to the loaded model

Comment: I found here :https://stackabuse.com/real-time-object-detection-inference-in-python-with-yolov7/    that torch.hub() doesn't support yet, and you can use detect.py script

Comment: solved it bro. i just removed "path=" .i gave just  "////"

Answer (score 0):

We can load Yolov7 Trained custom model with the help of following script.
We are running the inference and drawing predicted bboxes.

```
import torch
import os
import cv2

# Load fine-tuned custom model
model = torch.hub.load('WongKinYiu/yolov7', 'custom', '/path/to/custom_model.pt',
                        force_reload=True, trust_repo=True)

    
# Declaring some variables    
TABLE_CONFIDENCE = 0.50
CELL_CONFIDENCE = 0.50
OUTPUT_DIR = 'output'

# Bounding Boxes color scheme
ALPHA = 0.2
TABLE_BORDER = (0, 0, 255)
CELL_FILL = (0, 0, 200)
CELL_BORDER = (0, 0, 255)

os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR, exist_ok=True)
    
# Run the Inference and draw predicted bboxes
results = model(image_path)
df = results.pandas().xyxy[0]
table_bboxes = []
cell_bboxes = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['class'] == 0 and row['confidence'] > TABLE_CONFIDENCE:
        table_bboxes.append([int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']),
                             int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])])

    if row['class'] == 1 and row['confidence'] > CELL_CONFIDENCE:
        cell_bboxes.append([int(row['xmin']), int(row['ymin']),
                            int(row['xmax']), int(row['ymax'])])

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
overlay = image.copy()
for table_bbox in table_bboxes:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (table_bbox[0], table_bbox[1]),
                  (table_bbox[2], table_bbox[3]), TABLE_BORDER, 1)

for cell_bbox in cell_bboxes:
    cv2.rectangle(overlay, (cell_bbox[0], cell_bbox[1]),
                  (cell_bbox[2], cell_bbox[3]), CELL_FILL, -1)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (cell_bbox[0], cell_bbox[1]),
                  (cell_bbox[2], cell_bbox[3]), CELL_BORDER, 1)

image_new = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, ALPHA, image, 1-ALPHA, 0)
image_filename = image_path.split('/')[-1]
cv2.imwrite(f'{OUTPUT_DIR}/{image_filename}', image_new)
```